# Cannot access "this" in Vue compnent filter

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-filter

The filter is defined in the component options like this:

```
Vue.extend({
  ...
  props: ['filterFn', ......],

  filters: {
    myFilter(value){
      return this.filterFn ? this.filterFn(value) : value;
    }
  },

  ...
});
```

And it uses a function that is passed as a property to the component.

But it doesn't work.

It tells me that it Cannot read property filterFn of undefined...

Comment: since filterFn is function passed from props you should use it as this.props.filterFn

Comment: same error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined. It seems it doesn't see "this" inside the filter

Comment: But `this` should resolve to something, right? How can it be `undefined`?

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan In strict mode it can be `undefined`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filters are not bound to the component instance.
Use a method instead.

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/why-does-this-inside-a-filter-function-is-undefined/18321
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5998